# UIBezierPath corner didn't show correct when radius equalTo height

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

Here is test code, you can copy and test:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let blueView = UIView(frame: .init(x: 20, y: 100, width: 100, height: 40))
    blueView.backgroundColor = .blue
    view.addSubview(blueView)
    let blueViewPath = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: blueView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: .init(width: 20, height: 20))
    let blueViewLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    blueViewLayer.frame = blueView.bounds
    blueViewLayer.path = blueViewPath.cgPath
    blueView.layer.mask = blueViewLayer
    
    let orangeView = UIView(frame: .init(x: 20, y: 150, width: 100, height: 40))
    orangeView.backgroundColor = .orange
    view.addSubview(orangeView)
    let orangeViewPath = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: orangeView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: .init(width: 40, height: 40))
    let orangeViewLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    orangeViewLayer.frame = orangeView.bounds
    orangeViewLayer.path = orangeViewPath.cgPath
    orangeView.layer.mask = orangeViewLayer
}
```

[image: result]

blueView and orangeView's height are both 40, blueView's radius is 20, orangeView's radius is 40.

But as you see the orangeView's radius looks like 20.

Why? How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624368-bezierpathwithroundedrect) please read out to know why its doing this

**bezierPathWithRoundedRect:byRoundingCorners:cornerRadii:**

> The radius of each corner oval. Values larger than half the
> rectangle’s width or height are clamped appropriately to half the
> width or height.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```swift
let orangeView = UIView(frame: .init(x: 150, y: 100, width: 260, height: 40))
orangeView.backgroundColor = .orange
view.addSubview(orangeView)
let orangeViewPath = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: .init(x: 0, y: -40, width: 260, height: 80), byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: .init(width: 40, height: 40))
let orangeViewLayer = CAShapeLayer()
orangeViewLayer.frame = orangeView.bounds
orangeViewLayer.path = orangeViewPath.cgPath
orangeView.layer.mask = orangeViewLayer
```